# Does session storage have a delay while fetching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storage, react-hooks, session-storage

In my react code, inside a component, I am fetching a value from session storage(inside useEffect hook). When console printed, it shows the value.
But inside the render(or return method), it does not have the value just fetched. Is there a delay while fetching from session storage?

Circumvented the problem after storing the same in state and fetching inside render!

```
let myValue = '';
useEffect(()=>{
    myValue = sessionStorage.getItem("someKey");
},[]);
// In the return method
return {
    <div>{myValue}</div>
}
```

Why does value fetched from session storage not available immediately in render?

Comment: Setting a private variable from 'useEffect' isn't going to cause a re-render. You might want to consider using `useState` so that you have a mechanism for setting the value and registering a re-render.

Comment: Yes! That's how I had circumvented the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you're expecting a variable value change to trigger a re-render. React doesn't work this way and you'll need another approach if you want to change a value and have it re-render:

Consider:

```
const [myValue, setMyValue] = useState('');

useEffect(()=>{
   setMyValue(sessionStorage.getItem("someKey"));
},[]);

// In the return method
return {
    <div>{myValue}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, both localStorage and sessionStorage calls are `sync`
You don't see the value in the render because the view is not re-rendered. You have to set a state, get a new props or force the render to see it.

**How to force update in hooks**

```
const [, updateState] = React.useState();
const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's available immediately

```
return {
    <div>{sessionStorage.getItem("someKey")}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, all sessionStorage calls are `synchronous`.